# Add dynamic picture in word document created using content type id and SharePoint Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, content-type, word

I have created a custom content type, base content type is document to create a form. I am able to view and update field values( text and date).
But, not getting image in the form.

I have tried using Developer/XML mapping and "insert field as picture" but seems it is not working.
I am using SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2):

This you can do with the Word Merge option: INCLUDEPICTURE:

1. Press CTRL + F9 it will insert { } tags
2. Make this of it:

   `{ INCLUDEPICTURE "" }`
3. Put you cursor between the double quotes.
4. And go to the XML Mapping choose your picture
5. select Url --> Insert Content Control --> Plain Text.
6. select the whole INCLUDEPICTURE and press F9 to refresh your fields.

You should see the picture now.

Comment: do i need to refresh every time while opening word document?

Comment: I think so, you can set a macro onload to refresh it for you:

Private Sub Document_Open()
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub

Comment: Macro won't work for document template in SharePoint online